# Can't find device lazy attributes in Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I develop IoT Agent with node.js library. And register device with this through IoTA:

```
'devices': [{
    'device_id': 'ULSensor',
    'entity_name': 'Sensor01',
    'entity_type': 'BasicULSensor',
    'attributes': [
        {
            'name': 't',
            'type': 'celsius'
        },
        {
            'name': 'l',
            'type': 'meters'
        }
    ],
    'lazy': [
        {
            'name': 'p',
            'type': 'pascal'
        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'type': 'curiosity'
        }
    ]                 
}]
```

Then make request to http://orion:1026/v1/queryContext with this payload:

```
data = {
    "entities": [{
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": 'Sensor01',
        "type": entity_type
    }]       
    , "attributes": [
        'c'
    ]
}
```

And got this:

```
  "errorCode" : {
    "code" : "404",
    "reasonPhrase" : "No context element found",
    "details" : "error forwarding query"
  }
```

But when set 't' in attributes - orion sends correct response. I wrote queryContextHandler and updateContextHandler in IoTA, but they were not called. Orion is a docker image, and node-lib from npm.

IoTA log shows that were two register requests:

```
"url": "http://orion:1026/NGSI9/registerContext",
"method": "POST",
"json": {
    "contextRegistrations": [
        {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "type": "BasicULSensor",
                    "isPattern": "false",
                    "id": "Sensor01"
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "p",
                    "type": "pascal",
                    "isDomain": "false"
                },
                {
                    "name": "c",
                    "type": "curiosity",
                    "isDomain": "false"
                }
            ],
            "providingApplication": "http://myiotagent:4042"
        }
    ],
    "duration": "P1M"
}

"url": "http://orion:1026/v1/updateContext",
"method": "POST",
"json": {
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "BasicULSensor",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Sensor01",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "t",
                    "type": "celsius",
                    "value": " "
                },
                {
                    "name": "l",
                    "type": "meters",
                    "value": " "
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

How to register device correctly or send query to orion to get lazy attributes?

Thanks!

**EDIT1**

`contextBroker --version` output:

1.7.0-next (git version: bd9f08cf86a631efe6dc1b078ac4c54648860aae)

and iotagent-node-lib version is 2.5.1

Comment: Could you edit your question in order to include Orion Context Broker version, pls? i.e., the output of `contextBroker --version`

Comment: I added version to question, hoping it help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion returns `"error forwarding query"` when it has tried to forward the request to the Context Provider (in your case, the IOTA plays the role of Context Provider) but have failed to do so. The tipical reason for this is a connection problem, e.g. Context Provider is down, network problems, etc.

Looking to your post, it seems you are using the following Context Provider endpoint:

```
"providingApplication": "http://myiotagent:4042"
```

That URL doesn't seem to be valid and could explain the problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It was problem with incorrect providing applications. I send request to 'v1/registry/discoverContextAvailability' in Orion, and found a lot of registrations with incorrect context provider endpoints for the same entity. Most of them were old, maybe Orion adds new record to this in every context registration event, I think. It seems that Orion try to connect to all of them.

Comment: Could you help me with another problem please? I registered device through IoTA with device_id = 'id10' and entity_name = 'name10'. It's ok with active attributes. But in request for lazy attributes to CB 'queryContext' endpoint with id = 'id10' I received error: 'No context element found'. In this case, CB doesn't make request to IoTA, it seems CB can't found entity. If I set id = 'name10' then get error: 'No device found'. And CB makes request to IoTA for device with id that equals to entity_name. It was incorrect device registration? But I don't change it in node-lib.

Comment: It would be better if you ask the new problem in a separate question. That way it would be more clear for community users to find the questions & answers information. Could you do that way, please? Thx!